# reading a pdf file and sending pdf response from servlet

Tags: java, servlets, pdf, web-applications

trying for a pdf download functionality in my application

I'm reading the pdf file in a servlet and trying to make it available to the client  through the servlet, below is the code

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        System.out.println("Inside HTTP Post" + request.getParameterNames());
        String pdfFileName = "C:\\test.pdf";

        ServletOutputStream outStream = null;
        BufferedInputStream inBuffer = null;

        try {
            outStream = response.getOutputStream();
            File pdf = new File(pdfFileName);
            response.setContentType("application/pdf");
            response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="
                    + "test.pdf");
            response.setContentLength((int) pdf.length());
            FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(pdf);
            inBuffer = new BufferedInputStream(input);
            int readBytes = 0, counter = 0;
            while ((readBytes = inBuffer.read()) != -1) {
                outStream.write(readBytes);
                System.out.println("The readBytes " + readBytes + "  "+ counter++);
            }
            System.out.println("After While");
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            System.out.println("Inside catch Block");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            System.out.println("Inside Filnally...");
            outStream.close();
            inBuffer.close();
        }
        System.out.println("End of method...");

    }
```

when debugging the control comes to while loop and `outStream.write(readBytes);` is called after some iteration, it stops

The SOP after while is not printed , also control is not coming to catch or finally Block.
and pdf is not getting downladed in browser.

I have refereed other similar post , but not able to find what i am doing wrong.
any help is appreciated

Comment: How big is the file? You really should use the other read method `read(byte[] b, int off, int len)` since `read()` goes one byte at a time.

Comment: Actually I would use `FileInputStream` and `read(byte[] b)`